# translation of a sentence involving antigen/buffer/solution

Tags: biochemistry

I'm trying to translate a sentence about biochemical testing into English.

So far, I can figure out the following:

*Make a 10,000 pg/ml stock solution **from[?]** antigen **into[?]** 7.5 % BSA-TSA buffer.*

The prepositions are the literal translations of what the foreign language says. However, despite knowing very little about biochemistry, I'm doubtful that either translation is correct in English.

If you were to read this sentence, would you be able to guess how to replace the highlighted words so that the phrase would sound idiomatic in English?

Comment: I'm not sure why "Deutsch" shows up in my profile (I'm not fluent in German), but the original sentence was in Finnish. If you can make sense of it, the sentence is *Tee antigeenista 10 000 pg/ml kantaliuos 7.5 % BSA-TSA puskuriin*.

Comment: I've done some more Googling since posting this, and it looks as though the correct formulation (in this context) might be "**from** the antigen ... **in** the buffer". What do others think?

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to prepare a stock solution of 10,000 pg/ml antigen in 7.5 % BSA-TSA buffer.